# Replace all the error level logs to the warning level in JS?

Tags: javascript, logging, error-handling

A part of the scripts e.g. `xhr.send(this.data)` fires e.g. `404 (Not Found)` error log on the console, but I need to avoid to have any error logs on the console because it affects the SEO of the page, so I need to replace all the errors on the console to instead be a warning.

I tried so far:

-

```
var console = (function(oldCons) {
   return {
       log: function(text) {
           oldCons.log(text);
       },
       info: function(text) {
           oldCons.info(text);
       },
       warn: function(text) {
           oldCons.warn(text);
       },
       error: function(text) {
           oldCons.warn(text);
       }
   };
}(window.console));
```

- 

```
// Override console.error to log as a warning
console.error = function () {
    originalError.apply(console, arguments);
    console.warn.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

- 

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function(event) {
    // Log the promise rejection as a warning
    console.warn("Unhandled Promise Rejection:", event.reason);
});
```

- 

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
   console.warn('Error: ' + message + '\n' + 'Script: ' + source + '\n' + 'Line: ' + lineno + '\n' + 'Column: ' + colno + '\n' + 'Stack trace: ' + error.stack);
   return true;
};
```

Though, none of the above didn't change the behavior.

Btw I also tried to error-handle the specific error of the part,

-

```
# socket = io();
let socket;
try {
  socket = io();
} catch (error) {
  console.warn("Error connecting to socket.io: ", error);
}
```

- 

```
try {
  xhr.send(this.data);
catch (error) {
  console.warn(error);
}
```

But this also didn't trick, still the `error` message on the console.

---

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't, and not by monkeypatching the `console` anyway. At best you can suppress them in your own browser. But what is printed on the console does not really affect SEO. If you want to fix this problem, solve it at the root, and do not make requests to non-existing resources.